# Could the link to migrated questions on other sites be made clearer?

Tags: feature-request, questions, migration, usability

Currently we are getting a list of things under a migrated question (something like the following):

> - migrated to **superuser.com** by `<name list>` æons ago
> - locked by Community♦ moments ago
> - closed as belongs on **superuser.com** by `<name list>` some time ago

The bolded parts are links which are named identically, but lead to different things. While "belongs on" logically gets just a link to the site (because there is nothing migrated yet), "migrated to" gets a link to the migrated question.

But to me I always struggle as the "superuser.com" link after "migrated to" isn't the first thing I'd expect to link to the actually migrated question. Maybe it's just me but I'd like something along the lines of

- migrated to superuser.com by `<name list>` æons ago:

  - `<link to migrated question using the question as title>`

or maybe extending the link to the whole phrase "migrated to superuser.com" would make things clearer. I don't know right now. I just noticed me pausing to think at least a few times recently with migrated questions, wondering which link would lead me to the migrated question. (According to Steve Krug we're always in a hurry and don't read but skim, so maybe my focus was just on the links and what they said and I coulnd't make much sense of them because I needed the context around them. But that seems to me a fundamentally human trait and possibly not specific to me.)